# animate background image with background size - jsfiddle updated

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to animate a background of a div element and I've got it to animate from some one else's code. The problem is the background's css attribute is background-size:cover so it show a duplicate of that image in it's animation, how do I create an animation of horizontal and vertical position of an image and not have a duplicate image showing after the animation is done? Is there a piece of code that can make it work the way I want it to or is there a plugin that can do this that has a zoom effect for background-size, P.S the background has to be background-size:cover because of an elastic web design, here is the code.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sny9H/)

```
$({temporary_x: 0, temporary_y: 0}).animate({temporary_x: -20, temporary_y: -20}, {
duration: 350,
step: function() {
    var position = Math.round(this.temporary_x) + "px " + Math.round(this.temporary_y) + "px";
    $("#image").css({"background-position":  position, backgroundSize: 'auto !important'});
    }
});
```

Comment: A jsfiddle would be better!

Comment: I added a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/sny9H/

Comment: what do you  want exactly zoom image or just some motion like in your fiddle with no image repeat

Comment: I would prefer it to zoom in and move to the left top by about 40px

Answer (score 0):

I changed the css a bit to stop the image from repeating itself.

```
#image {
 background-size: cover;
 background: url(http://ts2.mm.bing.net/th?id=H.4546305711735429&w=240&h=133&c=7&rs=1&pid=1.7) no-repeat;
 width: 240px; 
 height: 133px;
```

}

Here's the [fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/5X5nJ/)

Hope it helps.

Comment: Yeah thats what I want now how do I get it to zoom in

Answer (score 0):

I think you're going to have an easier time without using the background image.  The background-size property is kinda new and behaves different in every browser.  I think just using an img element and scaling it on hover would be a little easier.
You would need to set the parent element to overflow:hidden

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using a pseudo element to contain the background.

It allows you to set the pseudo element to 100% size initially, but afertwards change it to whatever you want.

If you set the position thru the right and bottom properties, then you need to move it very little (or may be nothing at all).

This is the CSS

```
#image {
    width:240px; height:133px; 
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#image:before {
    background-size:cover;
       background-image:url(http://ts2.mm.bing.net/th?id=H.4546305711735429&w=240&h=133&c=7&rs=1&pid=1.7);
        content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    right: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    transition: 0.3s all;
}

#image:hover:before {
    width: 110%;
    height: 110%;
    right: -5px;
    bottom: -5px;
}
```

and the Javascript is gone.

[updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vals/sny9H/1/)